# How do I make an image a part of my html.ActionLink?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This is probably a really simple question. How do I add an image to an `Html.ActionLink` link? In regular **HTML** I would just put something like this:

```
 <a href="url"><img src="whatever.jpg" />Words and Stuff too </a>
```

How can I embed the image within the generated link tag?

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Change Database Connection","Index","Home",null,null)
```

I've tried doing this

```
 @Html.ActionLink("<img src=\"../../Content/themes/base/images/web_database.png\" />Change Database Connection","Index","Home",null,null)
```

Obviously this didn't work.It just displayed my `img` tag in plain text. What is the correct way to achieve this? Am I going to need a **helper class** for something so simple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two extensions I have adopted and updated.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionImageLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string imageUrl, string altText, string actionName, string controller, object routeValues, string _imageClass = "", object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    var image = new TagBuilder("img");
    image.MergeAttribute("src", imageUrl);
    image.MergeAttribute("alt", altText);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_imageClass) == false) image.MergeAttribute("class", _imageClass);
    var link = helper.ActionLink("[replaceme]", actionName, controller, routeValues, htmlAttributes);
    return new MvcHtmlString(link.ToHtmlString().Replace("[replaceme]", image.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing)));
}

public static MvcHtmlString ActionImageLink(this HtmlHelper helper, string imageUrl, string altText, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, string _imageClass = "", object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    var image = new TagBuilder("img");
    image.MergeAttribute("src", imageUrl);
    image.MergeAttribute("alt", altText);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_imageClass) == false) image.MergeAttribute("class", _imageClass);
    var link = helper.ActionLink("[replaceme]", routeValues, htmlAttributes);
    return new MvcHtmlString(link.ToHtmlString().Replace("[replaceme]", image.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing)));
}
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't compile with 'helper.ActionLink'. I get an error 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and no extension method 'ActionLink' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found. Is there a library I need to add?

Comment: You need to include a reference to System.Web.Mvc and add to the class file `using System.Web.Mvc;`, finally, add a using to where you use the extension pointing to the class file of the extension.

Comment: Got it now. I had System.Web.MVC and System.Web.Routing added to my class but it wouldn't work until I added 'using System.Web.Mvc.Html;'. Doesn't make any sense to me but works great

Comment: Oh yes, i see that reference now too. Thanks for pointing it out.